# Add-SPOTheme : The term 'Add-SPOTheme' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: pnp-powershell, sharepoint-online-powershell

I am trying to apply a custom theme color to my SharePoint online site from an article I got online.  Im running it in SharePoint online Management shell.  I have the latest version of SPO management shell, it shows:
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_extenderversion:SR|16.0.0.12003
I've run the: Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline cmd line
I've also run the following: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
but I get the following error: 
Connect-SPOService : The term 'Connect-SPOService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
 AND 
Add-SPOTheme : The term 'Add-SPOTheme' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
My script looks like this:

```
    $SPThemeName = "My Custom colors"

$SPThemePalette = const myTheme = @{
"themePrimary" = "#5d5daf";
"themeLighterAlt" = "#f7f7fc";
"themeLighter" = "#e0e0f2";
"themeLight" = "#c7c7e7";
"themeTertiary" = "#9595d0";
"themeSecondary" = "#6d6db9";
"themeDarkAlt" = "#54549e";
"themeDark" = "#474786";
"themeDarker" = "#343463";
"neutralLighterAlt" = "#faf9f8";
"neutralLighter" = "#f3f2f1";
"neutralLight" = "#edebe9";
"neutralQuaternaryAlt" = "#e1dfdd";
"neutralQuaternary" = "#d0d0d0";
```

"neutralTertiaryAlt" = "#c8c6c4";
"neutralTertiary" = "#a19f9d";
"neutralSecondary" = "#605e5c";
"neutralSecondaryAlt" = "#8a8886";
"neutralPrimaryAlt" = "#3b3a39";
"neutralPrimary" = "#323130";
"neutralDark" = "#201f1e";
"black" = "#000000";
"white" = "#ffffff";
}

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force

```
cls
if(Get-module -ListAvailable -Name "Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell") {
    Write-Host "SharePoint Online module already installed" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else {
    Write-Host "Installing latest version of SharePoint Online module" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Force
}

Connect-SPOService -Url <myURL> -credential <myUsername>

Add-SPOTheme -Identity $SPThemeName -Palette $SPThemePalette -IsInverted $false

Write-Host "Your Fluent UI Theme '"$SPThemeName "' is now added to SharePoint.`n Go to a web site and Change the Look." -ForegroundColor Green

Set-ExecutionPolicy Default -Force
```

Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell - It says it is already installed

I'm running this in Windows Powershell ISE with admin privileges.  I'm importing the SharePoint Online Man module, but it still tells me the term Connect-SPOService and Add-SPOTheme is not recognized
Please Help?

Comment: Try using latest version `16.0.23408.12000`. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I've installed the SPO Manament Powershell and it says: Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 16.0.23408.12000
But still give same error

Answer (score 1):

Your script is connecting to SharePoint using a cmdlet from the PnP.PowerShell module but is then using the Add-SPOTheme cmdlet from the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell module.

To connect to SharePoint using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell, you should use [Connect-SPOService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/connect-sposervice?view=sharepoint-ps).

Additionally, make sure the PowerShell module is loaded by using Import-Module at the start of your script:

```
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Comment: Thank you Callum.  I have installed the SharePoint Online management shell and tried to run only the command: Connect-SPOService there.  It says the term Connect-SPOService is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function ect.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you include the "Import-Module" line at the start of your script?

Comment: I've edited my original question with the full script

Comment: Your script doesn't use Import-Module, we're not questioning whether it is installed but whether it has been imported to the current session.

Comment: Apologies, the first line was not copied - I start the script with Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePOint.Powershell.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, you're using two different Stack Exchange accounts? I'm guessing there is a problem with your PowerShell setup, if it's not importing correctly. This might be beyond the scope of SharePoint StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very nice solution on SharePointDiary.com that uses Powershell script (not SPO Man shell) - It works perfectly.

> #Define the color palette $ThemePalette = @{ "themePrimary" = "#00d492"; "themeLighterAlt" = "#f3fdfa"; "themeLighter" = "#d0f8eb";
> "themeLight" = "#a9f2db"; "themeTertiary" = "#5ce5b9";
> "themeSecondary" = "#1ad99c"; "themeDarkAlt" = "#00be82"; "themeDark"
> = "#00a16e"; "themeDarker" = "#007751"; "neutralLighterAlt" = "#f8f8f8"; "neutralLighter" = "#f4f4f4"; "neutralLight" = "#eaeaea";
> "neutralQuaternaryAlt" = "#dadada"; "neutralQuaternary" = "#d0d0d0";
> "neutralTertiaryAlt" = "#c8c8c8"; "neutralTertiary" = "#ae9e9e";
> "neutralSecondary" = "#938181"; "neutralPrimaryAlt" = "#796767";
> "neutralPrimary" = "#0f0b0b"; "neutralDark" = "#443636"; "black" =
> "#2a2020"; "white" = "#ffffff"; }
> #Set Admin Center URL $AdminCenterURL = ""
> #Connect to SharePoint Online - Prompt for credentials Connect-SPOService -url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
> #Add new SharePoint Online theme Add-SPOTheme -Name "Theme name" -Palette $ThemePalette -IsInverted $False

#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/11/sharepoint-online-add-custom-theme-using-powershell.html#ixzz7wm0mJBJt